SquashFS explanation for Android system
I have an Android Pioneer car audio tablet. I want to root the firmware. I managed to backup firmware by taking the eMMC chip and backup partition. For many days, I was trying to unpack system.img, but then I found it was SquashFS and not ext4. I downloaded the Windows 10 WSL Linux terminal, fixed everything, and succeeded to unsquashfs the system. Now the difficulty is with which command I will make the folder like the original system.img.
I tried mksquashfs system.img but something is not right with the final file. The original is 2 GB, and the modded is 1 GB. I can't get how compress has to be made to be like the original.
Here is the link to the original system, just unzip the file for someone to help me.

According to some gist I have found for modifying the squashfs image it is better not to unpack it but directly mount and modify it using the common Linux file operation tools: https://gist.github.com/natsumerinchan/7a7a819538dfb44d997475ab889d6b47

When I download and "unsquashfs" your system.img file, I get a directory of 1.82 GB. Could I ask what Pioneer model number this is for?
